# Mean estimation under known variance heterogeneity

Tags: variance, mean, heteroscedasticity, point-estimation, efficiency

We observe $X_1,\ldots,X_N$ and consider following model:
$$
X_i = \theta + w_i\epsilon,\quad \epsilon \sim N(0, 1).
$$
Based on above model, we want to estimate $\theta$ given $X_1,\ldots,X_N$ and $w_1, \ldots, w_N$.
Let $\bar{X}$ be sample mean of $X_1,\ldots,X_N$.
Of course $X_i$ and $\bar{X}$ are members of unbiased estimators of $\theta$.

I'm interested in **better estimator** (in some sense) than above. Are there anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum likelihood estimator will be the weighted mean $X_w = \frac{\sum 1/w_i^2 X_i}{\sum 1/w_i^2}$.

It will be unbiased and will have the smallest variance of $ 1/\sum(1/w_i^2)$, i.e. it is better than a simple mean or any $X_i$

Comment: I missed about MLE. Thanks. But How can we confirm the variance minimality of $X_w$?

Comment: The reason is the Cramer-Rao bound https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound which gives the limit on variance of unbiased estimators. And MLE with the likelihood that is exactly Gaussian gives you a Cramer-Rao bound, i.e. estimator with the smallest possible variance.